# how to select and update 10 random row in laravel and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

i have a Blog with multi managers.
i want to check if manager has not any Post for check i give him 10 post to check
i have o column in my database named 'Worker' and i set it to '1' 
i must check if user hasent any row with their userID i change 10rows 'Worker' to their userid
its my try but i cant say change how many rows

```
if (UncheckedLottery::where('Worker',\Auth::id())->count() == 0){
                    UncheckedLottery::where('Worker' , 1)->update(['Worker' => \Auth::id()]);
                }
```

Comment: In mysql it is possible to put a [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) to your update query. It might also be possible to do it with the query builder. Try `->limit(10)->update(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
if (UncheckedLottery::where('Worker',\Auth::id())->count() == 0){
                UncheckedLottery::where('Worker' , 1)->limit(10)->update(['Worker' => 
                   \Auth::id()]);
            }
```